# AssertFalse in Robotium Not Working

Tags: robotium

Am trying to validate some data in the view using Robotium.

I have written the below code for the same:

```
    NegativeExpected=false;
    solo.clickOnButton(0);

    solo.sleep(10000);

    actual= solo.searchText("Jan-12");
    actual= solo.searchText("Feb-12");
    actual= solo.searchText("Jul-12");
    actual= solo.searchText("Aug-12");

    assertEquals(NegativeExpected,actual);
```

Here what I am trying to do is to check the presence of the list of data and if present the test case has to fail. ie., AssertFalse operation.

But even when the values are present, the test case is never failing and is passing. Am really not able to understand why its happening so. Am really at a fix.

Please help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `assertEquals(NegativeExpected,actual);`after every

```
actual= solo.searchText("Jan-12");("Feb-12")..
```

because in your present code, it is checking the assert condition only for the last

```
actual= solo.searchText("Jan-12");
```

or you can define them as `actual1, actual2...`and use and/or operator among them in your final `assertEquals(..)`according to your requirement.

and if negative expected is noy working then try `!actual`as

```
assertEquals(Expected,!actual);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this id:

```
AssertFalse(solo.searchText("Jan-12"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this for each one.

```
actual &= solo.search("xxx")；
```

so that you won't lost your total actual value.